# Passing an Array or Range through a function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I want to make a basic function that takes an average of values that I highlight in Excel. I am well aware there is already a built-in function in Excel for this but I am trying to make one as practice.

My problem is I am not sure how to pass a range and then call on specific elements in the Range.

Below is the pseudo code I've been playing around with. I understand it may be horribly written. I am a beginner and I just want to get some practice.

```
Function averagetest(range As Range) '<------(Is this how I pass a Range into a function?)
      Dim N as Integer
      Dim i as Integer
      Dim average as Double
      average = 0 
      N = LengthofRange '<--------- (Is there a way to get the length of the 
      range like UBound or LBound for an array?)
      Do Until i = LengthofRange
          average = average + Range(i, i+1) '<--------(Is this how you call a 
          specific element in the range? I'm just adding every element in the 
          Range)
          i = i + 1
      Loop
average = average/N

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assume a `Range` is going to be contiguous, nor can you assume a `Range` is going to be horizontal, nor vertical.

A `Range` is a collection of objects, so you iterate it with a `For Each` loop for optimal performance.

Assuming the function is meant to be used as a UDF worksheet function, and therefore is defined in a *standard module* (.bas):

```
Public Function AverageTest(ByVal target As Range) As Variant

    Dim total As Double
    Dim count As Double

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In target
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            total = total + cell.Value
            count = count + 1
        'Else
        '    AverageTest = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        '    Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    If count = 0 Then
        AverageTest = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
    Else
        AverageTest = total / count
    End If

End Function
```

Note:

- Parameter is passed `ByVal`, and isn't named after an existing type (`Range`); we don't need a reference to the range pointer, a copy of it is good enough.
- Function is explicitly `Public`, and has an explicit return type (`Variant`).
- Function returns a `Variant`, so as to return a `Double` result in the "happy path", or an appropriate `Error` value (`#Div/0!`) when applicable.
- Function is only counting numeric cells, which means it works even if the `target` range contains error values. The commented-out code would bail out and return a `#VALUE!` error if a non-numeric value is encountered.

---

How you "pass the range" is the caller's problem. There are many ways you can do this - from an Excel formula:

```
=AverageTest(A1:A10)
=AverageTest(A1:B12,F4:L4)
```

You can also use it in VBA code:

```
foo = Module1.AverageTest(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `range` as a variable.

Then you can use rows.Count or Columns.Count to get the extent

```
Function averagetest(rng As Range)
      Dim N as Integer
      Dim i as Integer
      Dim average as Double
      average = 0 
      N = rng.rows.count 
      For  i = 1 to N 'use For loop
          average = average + rng.cells(i,1)'Cells will work here
      Next i
      averagetest= average/N

End Function
```

Or you can do this -- there's not really any need to iterate over the count of cells, when you can just iterate over `Each` cell in the `rng.Cells` collection. I would also change the variable name from `average` (which is misleading) to something a bit more descriptive, like `total`:

```
Option Explicit
Function averagetest(rng As Range)
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim total As Double

    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        total = total + cl.Value
    Next
    averagetest = total / rng.Cells.Count

End Function
```

As a bonus, this latter method would work on a 2-dimensional range as well.

Note that this will treat empty cells as 0-values (the `AVERAGE` worksheet function ignores empty cells, so your results may vary) and it will raise an error if there are non-numeric values in the range.